HSL Inside Dark Mode Conditional Not Apply Correctly
I have a project set up with Next.js and shadcn, and I'm trying to apply CSS variables based on system preferences (light/dark mode). Here's what I'm seeing:
When using simple CSS variables like this, everything works as expected:
@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: white;
    --foreground: black;
  }

  .dark {
    --background: black;
    --foreground: white;
  }
}

I also confirmed that using HSL values inside the :root works correctly in light mode:
@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 20 14.3% 4.1%; /* Renders the background black */
    --foreground: black;
  }

  .dark {
    --background: white;
    --foreground: black;
  }
}

However, as soon as I use HSL for both light and dark mode conditionals, the values no longer get overridden when my system changes to dark mode (confirmed via devtools). Here's the problematic code:
@layer base {
  :root {
    --background: 0 0% 100%; /* Light mode */
    --foreground: 240 10% 3.9%;
  }

  .dark {
    --background: 20 14.3% 4.1%; /* Dark mode */
    --foreground: 0 0% 95%;
  }
}

What I've Tried:
Using HSL without conditionals works.
Using conditionals without HSL also works.
Specifically, combining HSL values with dark mode conditionals doesn't seem to work.
Any insights into why HSL values in dark mode aren’t being applied correctly?

Is this pure css or is it tailwind? if you're using  tailwind try doing the tailwind way.

another thing is to wrap your hsl like this hsl(20 14.3% 4.1%)

i am using tailwind css with the shadcn theme provided here https://ui.shadcn.com/themes. Literally copied the code.
Wrapping hsl(20 14.3% 4.1%) weirdly works (I dont really get why). But it chanegs the css. I.e. the base light mode css looks completely different and much worse with the hsl wrap.

tightly follow the doc here, do not forget to configure components.json, globals.css and tailwind.config.js
